# Method for generic creating of Instance from sub class in java

Tags: java, generics

I have an abstract superclass:

```
class abstract Father{
public static boolean controll(){here comes code....}
}

class child1 extends Father{
public static boolean controll(){
   does something....
   Father.controll();
}}
```

In my main Class I initiate children like this

```
if(Child1.controll()){ new Child1().callingOtherMethod()}
if(Child2.controll()){ new Child2().callingOtherMethod()}
```

And so on many times....

I still very new to generics and not quite undertand it.
How do I write in my main class a method more generic, that does something like that:

```
public void moveToStep(Class<? extends Father> clasz){  
    if(clasz.controll()) 
      new clasz().callingOtherMethod()   }
```

so I can call it in shorter form:

```
moveToStep(Child1.class);  moveToStep(Child1.class); ...
```

May be Im wrong trying to use generic. Not sure what is the right way to avoid all this repeating in the main class

Comment: Do you need the methods to be `static`?

Comment: Yes, because I test if I need to create the objects upon given parametters before making an instance. That would save me a lot of unneeded objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, include the method you want to call as abstract in the superclass.

```
abstract class Father {
    public static boolean predicate() { /*...*/ }

    protected abstract void method();
}
```

Then, make sure your subclasses include an empty constructor.

```
final class Child1 extends Father {
    Child1() { /*...*/ }

    public static boolean predicate() { return true; }

    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Child1");
    }
}
```

Have a look at the docs for [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html). Use reflection to call the predicate (`controll` in your example), and then [`newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) to instantiate a class and call the other method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Class<? extends Father>> children =
            Arrays.asList(Child1.class, Child2.class);
    for (Class<? extends Father> c: children) {
        try {
            Method pred = c.getDeclaredMethod("predicate");
            Boolean b = (Boolean) pred.invoke(null);
            if (b.booleanValue()) {
                Father f = (Father) c.newInstance();
                f.method();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3170595 I'm glad I could help. Don't forget to accept an answer, if any of the answers posted here solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are looking for is in java.lang.reflect. You can try using

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--

This will only work if there is a null constructor. Otherwise you'll need to find a constructor also using reflection on figure out what values to pass in to it.

Comment: I changed it to:     public void moveToStep(Class<? extends Father> clasz) {try{ if(clasz.controll())   clasz.getInstance(); ...)}  But the programm doesnt recognize clasz as type of Father and can not find method controll() respectly to clasz

Comment: @user3170595 this is a new question. If you need an answer for this too, you should post it independently of this question